# pre-commit setuptools can't find attribute "CompileError"

Tags: python, python-typing

I'm currently trying to commit changes to my local fork of a public repository. They have pre-commit hooks; one of which is `mypy`. I've been getting the following error when this hook is initiated:

```
/path/to/file.py:1: error: Module "setuptools._distutils.errors" has no attribute "CompileError"  [attr-defined]
```

So I assume that the `virtualenv` that the pre-commit is creating has an old version of `setuptools` which does not have `setuptools._distutils.errors.CompileError`.

The next thing I do is isolate the `mypy` pre-commit virtualenv by only running its hook and then going to `~/.cache/pre-commit/`. In this directory I see

```
README
db.db
repoe60db_7v
repowh6yi5g5
```

In `repowh6yi5g5` there is just a `setup.py`, `LICENSE`, and `README.md`.

In `repoe60db_7v` there is

```
LICENSE 
build                   
py_env-python3.10
README.md
pre_commit_placeholder_package.egg-info setup.py
```

And then going into `py_env-python3.10` I see

```
bin
lib
pyenv.cfg
```

I then `source /bin/activate` to activate the environment living there. I *assume* this is the virtualenv that pre-commit uses? (this is all very new to me). Then, once in that environment, `pip list` yields

```
Package                        Version
------------------------------ --------
mypy                           1.1.1
mypy-extensions                1.0.0
numpy                          1.24.2
pip                            23.0.1
pre-commit-placeholder-package 0.0.0
setuptools                     67.6.0
tomli                          2.0.1
types-filelock                 3.2.7
types-setuptools               67.6.0.0
typing_extensions              4.5.0
wheel                          0.38.4
```

I then check `setuptools 67.6.0` (the newest version) and in their source code they sure enough have `setuptools._distutils.errors.CompileError`. I don't know what I'm doing wrong!

Any help is appreciated :)

I tried what I outlined above.